# For Gilbert Strang's Calculus textbook, are there any recommended problem lists?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I am studying this book as a companion text for my calculus course(because my current textbook is a mess). However, I am not entirely sure which problems I should work through for each section.

My two questions are as follows: Are there any suggested/recommended problem lists for the textbook that are available online? If not, how does one select which problems to work through in each section?

Thanks,

RR